# Can I change my mind if "I hate hats"?

Tags: support, winter-bash

While I don't wear them I do like see what hats I can collect without trying. I first acknowledged that "I love hats" in order to be able to have that privilege.

[image: I hate hats]

Today I felt the option "I hate hats" calling out to me. I will assume that it will collapse or remove the Winter Bash icon from my profile?

Is this an irreversible action? Does it just hide the hats earned? Would I lose my hat progress? What happens when I push the ["red button"](https://keithcrane.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/button.jpg)?

Comment: [See, that's why do we need to replace *hate* with *ate* since *hate* isn't clear in this case.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270833/why-do-i-have-to-hate-hats/270835#comment877682_270835)

Comment: @KevinGuan Agreed, though you have to admit... the immature verbiage is fitting for the asinine feature.

Comment: just click on the correspondant button i hate hats

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After you "hate" your hats, you can re-enable it. You don't lose your hats. I can confirm this as I pressed the button by mistake and still have all my hats.

Comment: And you survived!

Comment: Do you still gain hats when you fulfill conditions while you hate them?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I would suspect know as your profile will stop recording the statistics required. Or they could just store the hats in a closet for you until you miss them

Comment: @Matt Badges are earned when the system checks if you have fulfilled conditions. Reputation can be re-calculated. If your profile "stops recording stats" does that mean that hats don't work in the same way as badges do? The system can't simply check the conditions and give you the hat if you re-enable them?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov You still gain hats during your "I hate hats" time.  I had turned it off for a few days, but had been awarded several new hats during the time it was off.

Answer (score 32):

If you push the red button you will be presented with the green button:

[image]

Comment: but "do you lose the hats?" is the most important question. when you decide that you love hats, do you start from zero :)

Comment: @Mih No, all the hats are preserved :)